# Changing focus on a GridView in DevExpress using Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, devexpress, devexpress-mvc

I'm working on a web application using `DevExpress` and `MVC 5`.

Is there a way to change the focused row of a `GridView` from Javascript, or at least remove the focus?

My app needs to update the focused row of a `GridView` according to the result of an `AJAX` call, but I can't figure out how to do that.

I've read about row handles but I couldn't find a clear example.

Is there a way to do this on the client side with `Javascript`?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `function SetFocusedRowIndex(visibleIndex : int);` if you have the row index or you can select the row by using `function SelectRowsByKey(key : object);`

You can have more informations in the Devexpress documentation :
https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/DevExpress.Web.MVC.Scripts.MVCxClientGridView.members